# How to write SMS application in blackberry?

Tags: networking, blackberry, sms

Can any one help me to write application to send and recieve sms in blackberry.If u can provide me some code snippet .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To send an sms:

```
import net.rim.device.api.io.*;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class SendSms extends Application
{
     private static final int MAX_PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH = 32;
     private String addr = "15191112222";
     private String msg = "This is a test message.";
     private DatagramConnection _dc = null;
     private static String _openString = "sms://";
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          new SendSms().enterEventDispatcher();
     }
     public SendSms()
     {
          try {
               _dc = (DatagramConnection)Connector.open(_openString);
               byte[] data = msg.getBytes();
               Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());
               d.setAddress("//" + addr);
               _dc.send(d);
          } catch ( IOException e) {}
          System.exit(0);
     }
}
```

To recieve an sms:

```
import net.rim.device.api.io.*;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ReceiveSms extends Application {
     private ListeningThread _listener;
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          new ReceiveSms().enterEventDispatcher();
     }
     ReceiveSms() {
          _listener = new ListeningThread();
          _listener.start();
     }
     private class ListeningThread extends Thread
     {
          private boolean _stop = false;
          private DatagramConnection _dc;
          public synchronized void stop()
          {
               _stop = true;
               try {
                    _dc.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.toString());
               }
          }
          public void run()
          {
               try {
                    _dc = (DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://");
                    for(;;)
                    {
                         if ( _stop ) {
                              return;
                         }
                         Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());
                         _dc.receive(d);
                         String address = new String(d.getData());
                         String msg = new String(d.getData());
                         System.out.println("Message received: " + msg);
                         System.out.println("From: " + address);
                         System.exit(0);
                    }
               } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.toString());
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ashraf thanks for ur help can u provide code to update the received msg in the screen because i tried myself but i could not able to achive.

Comment: What do you mean by "updating the received messsage" ? 
Can you explain this in more details ?

Comment: Hey Ashraf i would like to display the recieved sms in the screen.How to do this?

Comment: You can replace the "System.out.println" and "System.err.println" functions with, for example,  the creation of a Dialog object (see http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Dialog.html), or you can show the message in a simple  LabelField (see http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/LabelField.html) you have many alternatives for the UI.

Answer (score 3):

It seems sending SMS from a BlackBerry is not always that simple. I thought I had it figured out, but it didn't work when the BlackBerry user was on a [CDMA network as opposed to GSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_wireless_communications_service_providers), which I was using.

I found the [solution here](http://www.handevel.com/?p=5) and adapted it to this. Different from that example is also the port number, I use port 5016 [as suggested on the Blackberry support forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/SMS-between-java-applications-on-Blackberries-between-CDMA-and/m-p/421915) and the [Blackberry knowledge center](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_is_-_Different_ways_to_send_SMS_messages.html?nodeid=1588663&vernum=0).

```
private static byte[] stringToByte(String s)
{
    char[] sa = s.toCharArray();
    byte[] ba = new byte[sa.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++) {
        ba[i] = (byte) (sa[i] & 0xFF);
    }

    return ba;
}

private static void sendCDMAText(String nr, String message) throws IOException
{
    DatagramConnection conn = (DatagramConnection) Connector.open("sms://+" + nr + ":5016");
    byte[] bytes = stringToByte(message);
    Datagram msg = conn.newDatagram(bytes, bytes.length);
    conn.send(msg);

}

private static void sendSMS(String nr, String message) throws IOException
{
    MessageConnection conn = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://" + nr);
    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) conn.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
    msg.setPayloadText(message);
    conn.send(msg);
}

public static void sendTextMessage(String nr, String message) throws IllegalArgumentException, InterruptedIOException, NullPointerException, SecurityException, IOException
{
    if (RadioInfo.getNetworkType() == RadioInfo.NETWORK_CDMA) {
        sendCDMAText(nr, message);
        return;
    }

    sendSMS(nr, message);
}
```

To send a text message, you would call it like this:

```
sendTextMessage("555123123", "The little text message you wanted to send.");
```

<sup>(Where *555123123* is a Hollywood phone number.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
public SendSms()
 {
      try {
           _dc = (DatagramConnection)Connector.open(_openString);
           byte[] data = msg.getBytes();
           Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());
           d.setAddress("//" + addr);
           _dc.send(d);
      } catch ( IOException e) {}
      System.exit(0);
 }
```

You dont set the message here ^^(data!)