# make desktop sms application using blackberry

Tags: .net, blackberry, sms

I have to make a SMS sending application in .NET, which uses the attached Blackberry handset(blackberry tour 9630 to be precise) to send SMS. I have never worked on smartphone application development, so want help in doing this. I searched SO for an answer and found one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968304/how-to-write-sms-application-in-blackberry), but its in java and i think that code would run on blackberry itself and not on desktop, correct me if i am wrong.
So if someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance to all those who reply.

Comment: BlackBerry dosen't suppport .NET, only J2ME. Or maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying quickly, I want to make a desktop software which will use the connected Blackberry device as a SMS gateway, I don't want it to run on the phone. I think I am clear now.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You should use an online SMS gateway instead.

Comment: try SMSLib its available for .net also.

Comment: hey michael, sending SMS from PC using blackberry is possible as i have seen some softwares which do it.The thing is that I can't use those software for my use.

Comment: hey vivart SMSLib only supports GSM devices.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Bluetooth on Mobile and connect with PC, it enumerate as COM(Serial Device),Test on Enumerated each "COM" port with AT Command Sets. in Hyper terminal and Use available code allover the web  to send SMS.