# make desktop sms application using windows mobile 6.1

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, sms

I have to make a SMS sending application in .NET which uses a connected CDMA based Windows mobile 6.1 device to send sms. The problem is I have never worked on smartphone app development so don't have any idea about how should i go about it. Couldn't find anything useful on SO or elsewhere, so please guide me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance to all those who reply.

P.S.:I posted a similar question regarding blackberry [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677130/make-desktop-sms-application-using-blackberry)

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919102.aspx) is the native library for sending SMS from the cell phone itself.

[Microsoft SMS Sender](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06a4f997-7f69-4891-8929-37b9041924a2&displaylang=en) may do what you need without writing any code at all.

Comment: hey thanks a lot for replying so quickly.
I checked Microsoft SMS sender,it supports only GSM handsets so can't use it.
The other link you gave looks good, but is this API for PC or the smartphone, I am a bit confused about it. So if you could give an example for the same , I would be really grateful.