# Is it possible to send the reply after reading the new incoming SMS or inbox SMS?

Tags: android, blackberry, java-me, mobile, symbian

I need to develop the SMS based application. I want to read the new incoming SMS or existing inbox SMS after that I want to send the reply for that SMS. I know its not possible in j2me. But my question is which platform is support this type of functionality? Like Symbian c++, Android, blackberry or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really isn't the language that will support the functionality you speak of, it's going to be the platform framework.  For instance, Java doesn't support this by default, but the Android platform does [support it](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) and it uses Java.  Blackberry also supports sending [SMS messages via Java](http://myhowto.org/java/j2me/22-sending-and-receiving-gsm-sms-on-blackberry-using-rim-apis/).  I imagine Symbian does as well.

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry supports this. 
I previously answered this question with sample code
[How to write SMS application in blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968304/how-to-write-sms-application-in-blackberry/1969217#1969217) 
Have a look on it.